# Ensamble OCR outputs from various engines like tesseract, cuneiform

Tags: python-3.x, ocr

Can you please suggest any approach to ensamble tesseract and cuneiform ocr outcomes since few things working well in tesseract and few in cuneiform. Thanks in advance.